# Can I animate a view to fade in from hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am trying to have a view `scrim` fade in on top of everything in my view controller after 5 seconds once the initial view loads. This is what I have right now.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self setupAlarmPoll];
[self setupTimeLabel];
self.shouldRefresh = YES;
[self refreshSpotifyToken];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                                             name:@"backHome"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                                             name:@"applicationDidEnterBackground"
                                           object:nil];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.00 animations:^{

       self.scrim.hidden = NO;
    }];



});
```

However, I don't get a gradual fade-in. The view just appears. How can I accomplish this animation in objective-c?

Comment: Try  `self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;`

Comment: in didLoad just make your scrim.alpha = 0 and in Animation section make it to 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hidden` property of a view is not animatable. The `alpha` property, however, **is** animatable.You need to:

1. Set the alpha to zero
2. Set hidden to false.
3. Animate the alpha to 1.0

By doing that you make the view no longer hidden, but completely transparent. The you animate the alpha property from 0.0 to 1.0, making the view fade in as desired.

The code would look like this:

```
self.scrim.alpha = 0;
self.scrim.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.00 
  delay: 5.0
  options: 0
  animations:^{
   self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;
  }
  completion: nil
];
```

(Note that the long form of animateWithDuration takes a delay parameter, so you don't have to wrap it in a call to `dispatch_after`.)

Also, why are you doing new development in Objective-C?

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, Duncan. I had tried animating the alpha property before but hadn't set the alpha to 0 first. The reason I'm using Objective-C is that the project was written by another developer, and I'm just modifying his code. I wish I could use Swift with it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it isn't `isHidden` you are looking for, it's the `alpha` property of the view. You see, `isHidden` will just straight up declare if something is 100% not able to be seen **at all** or not. And as such you can not animate the `isHidden` property of a `UIView`. But this is where the `alpha` property comes to the rescue, because it is intended to be used exactly as you are trying to with `isHidden`. The alpha property determines how *faded* a `UIView` is on screen. So if the `alpha` is at `0`, it's hidden. So if you set your view's `alpha` to `0` then use the follow code you can fade in the view:

```
// Swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { 
    view.alpha = 1
}

// Objective-C
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 ^{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense!

Answer (score 2):

Either animate `alpha` as others have mentioned, or use `transitionWithView` with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrim.hidden = true;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.scrim duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        self.scrim.hidden = false;
    } completion:nil];
}
```